# horizontal alternative columns with transpose

Tags: google-sheets, transpose

Transposing rows in alternate columns
Suppose I have a continuous row

```
A1 = 1 A2 = 2 A3 = 3 A4 = $
```

I need to transpose it to

```
B1 = 1 D1 = 2 F1 = 3 H1 = 4
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 1):

```
=TRANSPOSE({A1; ""; A2; ""; A3; ""; A4})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is it possible something like =TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA({A1:A,""}) or Somrthing simmiliar, basically I dont know how many rows may come in future

Comment: @AmodAjitKarmarkar nope, there isn't such formula. when I do something similar I usually first populate it in order and then I use a recorded macro of "adding new row/column after every entry" - it takes like 1-2minute to complete and its fun to watch too

Answer (score 0):

```
={A1, "", A2, "", A3, "", A4}
```

[image]

if you are not US localized use: **`={A1\ ""\ A2\ ""\ A3\ ""\ A4}`**

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
=if(isodd(column()),"",OFFSET($A1,int(column()-2)/2,))
```

in B1 and copy across to the right (assuming LTR).